# Transforming category based data into column for time series chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've got data that looks like this -

| task type | date | end time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| task A | 2023-07-01 | 1:00 AM |
| task B | 2023-07-01 | 9:00 AM |
| task A | 2023-07-02 | 1:01 AM |
| task B | 2023-07-02 | 9:05 AM |
| task A | 2023-07-03 | 1:02 AM |
| task B | 2023-07-03 | 9:01 AM |

I'd like to have a chart which looks something like

```
  |   a a a
  | a       a
t |
  |       b
  | b b b   b
  +-------------
      date
```

I think to chart this in Excel as two series plotting the end time over the dates I need to transform it into something like this -

| date | task A end time | task B end time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 1:00 AM | 9:00 AM |
| 2023-07-02 | 1:01 AM | 9:05 AM |
| 2023-07-03 | 1:02 AM | 9:01 AM |

but I'm drawing a blank on how I'd go about that kind of transformation, or indeed whether I need to do that to chart it properly.

Looking for advice / tips on how I could do that transformation and charting. Have 5 years of daily time data for multiple tasks so really looking to avoid doing it by hand. Running on Excel 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a unique set of dates:  `=UNIQUE($B$2:$B$7)`

And then a lookup to return task A and task B for each date:
`=XLOOKUP($A10 & B$9,$B$2:$B$7 & $A$2:$A$7,$C$2:$C$7)` with some mixed relative/absolute referencing so you can drag the formula across and down.

As an alterative to `XLOOKUP` and providing each day doesn't have repeated tasks you could use SUMIFS:  `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7,$A16,$A$2:$A$7,B$9)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you - learning about that & operator in the conditions, that's handy.